# Vaadin withNullRepresantation ComboBox<Integer>

Tags: java, vaadin

I want solve this problem, from Combobox numbers I can select null value (means not required) but withNullRepresentation(0) is problem cause I want send to DB number not chosen number as null, cause I use it later in Grid and want show empty value in column if null saved, I mean if saved value is null Integer( or int 0) convert in grid to empty string ... I do stupid hack, can Vaadin convert something like IntegerToStringConverter if value not selected and I want parse null integer from DB to Grid like empty string?

Comment: Please read into [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I see many times longer questions then mine

Comment: The length has nothing to do with it. You've provided no workings of your own and the problem is relatively unclear

Comment: from my perspective is clear and i got answer so?

Comment: That doesn't make the question any better.

Comment: if you dont understand question doesnt mean everybody else understand

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I believe that what @Jay is trying to suggest, is to always think _"if someone unfamiliar with my problem reads this question, will they be able to understand my issue?"_ and _"what minimum information can I provide to the reader so they can quickly figure out the context and reproduce the issue?"_. This also helps other people to understand if they have the same problem, and easily get an answer. Imagine how it would be for you to find an answer to your issue in a few minutes with a quick search, instead of waiting for someone to notice and then answer your own question. Awesome, right!? :-)

Comment: sometimes i have to read 10x times questions and answers to understand cause some problems cannot be described in one sentence, btw I tried many times put question simple and I got answer to not make simple questions and rewrite it, sorry but validation of Q/A here is too much overhead, you do camel from fly :-D

Comment: I'm sure you did, and it's normal to happen since a lot of people don't speak english natively. However, I think there has been some misunderstanding, we're NOT suggesting shorter questions, we're suggesting more towards complete questions. That is, a description of the issue (what you are expecting and what is actually happening), and the minimum amount of code needed to quickly reproduce the problem.

Comment: As the one writing the answer, I can tell you that I had to make quite many assumptions and guesses about what the question actually was about.

Comment: It would have been much easier to come up with an answer if the structure of the question would first describe what you want to achieve without going into any solutions, and then there would have been a separate description of what you tried to do and why that didn't lead to the result you wanted. That description should preferably also have contained some additional code snippets, e.g. how the problematic `Grid` column was defined.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand what was that they say... "assumption is the mothe of all f*** ups"?  :-) petmik, a bit of context just FYI, Leif is part of the [Vaadin team](https://vaadin.com/company/team)

Comment: I discover Vaadin last month, best UI ever and effectively doing apps and themes then solve tons of problems then in shity javascript and html frameworks and server, I got some skills so I promise it was my last question Im in depresion that vaadin team gives me minus points here :-D

Comment: Don't get depressed, it's not a trial nor a witch hunt, just try to see what you can gather from the constructive feedback your getting, so you can improve yourself, as well as your next questions. No one knows everything, so everyone benefits from knowledge sharing done right, both in form of questions and answers.

Comment: Yes, please keep asking! We from the Vaadin team also learn things just be seeing what things people are asking about, even in cases when we know some answers.

Answer (score 1):

`withNullRepresentation` is intended for the situation where there might be  `null` values in the database, but you don't want those `null` values be passed to the component. This is typically not the case with `ComboBox` where `null` is the same as an empty selection.

My recommendation is thus to not use `withNullRepresentation` when binding to a `ComboBox`. You can configure how the empty selection is displayed to the user using `ComboBox.setEmptySelectionCaption(String)` if the default setting of `""` isn't suitable for your case.

Then when you want to show the value in e.g. a Grid, you can configure for that column how to handle the value. When you configure your column using something like `grid.addColumn(item -> item.getNumber()`, then Grid will internally do something like `String.valueOf(value)` for actually showing the value. This will cause `null` values to be displayed as `"null"`.

One way around this is to explicitly do the string conversion in a way that handles `null` values in a different way, e.g. `grid.addColumn(item -> Objects.toString(item.getNumber(), ""))`. Another alternative is to configure your column to use a `NumberRenderer` which by default represents null values as `""`. You can do this as `grid.addColumn(item -> item.getNumber(), new NumberRenderer())`

Comment: thanks NumberRenderer will solve this problem to Grid

Comment: problem is in combobox I have to put some number Integer, not null or empty string, so I decide if nothing chosen in combox save -1 and in Grid I did this, cause NumberRenderer has no predicate parameter, which should be looks better with setRenderer()                                                                                             
`personGrid.addColumn(col -> col.getAge() == -1 ? new NumberRenderer("-") : col.getAge()).setCaption(bundle.getString("label.age"));`

Comment: As long as the "empty selection allowed" setting is `true` (which is also the default value) in ComboBox, then `null` will be a valid value even if it's not included in the options configured through `setItems` or `setDataProvider`.

But if you still have `-1` values in the database, then you can convert them in the Grid column's `ValueProvider`, e.g. `grid.addColumn(person -> person.getAge() != -1 ? person.toString() : "")`.

Comment: yes I have to save some null or -1 to discover to render my value in grid later, other problem is in binding if I removeBean in my form and my DAO = null to save next data, I select empty combo and got error in Person::getAge, setAge, ,still solve it  where in order put binders, where null my dao, when validate, its tricky